# Invalid MEX-file due to undefined symbol

Tags: c++, matlab, linker, symbols

I am trying to build MEX modules, but I am having runtime issues with undefined symbols. Here is the output

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/glperez/issm/trunk-jpl/lib/TriMesh.mexa64':
/home/glperez/issm/trunk-jpl/lib/libISSMCore.so: undefined symbol: _ZN14ToolkitOptions14toolkitoptionsE

Error in triangle (line 40)
[elements,x,y,segments,segmentmarkers]=TriMesh(domainname,riftname,area);

Error in test101 (line 1)
md=triangle(model(),'../Exp/Square.exp',50000.);
```

Checking the symbols in 'libISSMCore.so' confirms the undefined symbol

```
$ nm ./lib/libISSMCore.so | grep 'toolkit'
U _ZN14ToolkitOptions14toolkitoptionsE
```

However, the symbol appears in 'TriMesh.mexa64':

```
$ nm ./lib/TriMesh.mexa64 | grep 'toolkit'
00000000002391b8 b _ZN14ToolkitOptions14toolkitoptionsE
```

As I understand it, the lowercase 'b' means that the symbol is in the uninitialized section and that it is local versus global.

Is the problem here have to do with the symbol being local, uninitialized or something else?

Comment: did you try linking against `libISSMCore.so` when building `TriMesh`? it would help if you show the compilation step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it, the lowercase 'b' means that the symbol is in the uninitialized section and that it is local

The symbol is local, and is in zero-initialized (aka BSS) section.

Yes, the problem is that it is local, i.e. no accessible outside of the `TriMesh.mexa64` library.